# Resharper not appearing in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

I recently downloaded resharper 7 for vs 2010 while my company sorted out my license. I finally got a license, so tried to enter it via the resharper dialog.  It stated I had a resharper 6 license, so it was not valid for 7.

I uninstalled v7 and installed v6.  However, now I cannot see resharper anywhere within vs.  There is no resharper option in the tools > options and it is not in help > About MS VS.

I have tried the normal things, such as repairing the installation, rebooting etc, but to no joy.

Any pointers on what to try would be great.

Comment: Personally, I'd get my company to get me a ReSharper 7 license.

Comment: When you installed ReSharper did you make sure to install it for VS2010? It seems obvious but I have forgotten to do that on occasion, especially when running multiple versions of VS.